# Excel Formula - Criteria to select the text with max corresponding value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am Looking to find the formula to select the text in **COL A**, with max corresponding value (**COL C**)

The below formula is not pulling in all the required Values under **COL A** against the specified criteria

```
 =IF($B$2:$B$719=G2,INDEX($A$2:$A$719,MATCH(MAX($C$2:$C$719),$C$2:$C$719,0)))
```

I would like the end result to look like COL H2 in the below image ;
[image]

Any help here would be much appreciated. Please and Thanks

I am using the below version of Excel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use filter and sort By:

```
=@SORTBY(FILTER(A:A,B:B=G2),FILTER(C:C,B:B=G2),-1)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response. Excel throws an error "That function is invalid". Looks like my version of excel does not support the "FILTER" function

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, I have tried this formula and works:

Copy the formula in the cell where you want the output. In this example is column G. After copy this formula for each cell in the column G.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$10,F2),IF(C2=MAX($C$2:$C$11),A2,""),"")
```

I dont' sure if the formula in English is correct(I don't know the correct name). In italian style is the following:

```
=SE(CONTA.SE($B$2:$B$11;F2);SE(C2=MAX.VALORI($C$2:$C$11);A2;"");"")
```

here an example:

[image]

Comment: I tried the formula,  =IF(COUNTIF($B:$B,G2),IF($C:$C=MAX($C:$C),A:A,""),""), unfortunately the values below columns G3 appear as "FALSE". Appreciate your help here

Comment: Try to write " " end no "" so you get the Empty Cell. In your comment the formula is wrong...No G2 but F2 and no A:A but Only A with the Number...